# How do I pass the mysql NOW() function from an array into a sanitized value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making an update database method and everything works as it should except when I try to add 'updated' => NOW() to $updateArray(). Obviously PDO sanitizes the mysql function leaving 0000-00-00 in the database.

```
public function update( $table, $id, $updateArray ) {

    $valuesArray = array_values( $updateArray );
    $valuesArray[] = $id;
    foreach ( $updateArray as $col => $value ) {
        $values .= "$col = ?, ";
    }
    $values = substr( $vals, 0, -2 );
    $query = $this->handle->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $values WHERE id = ?");

    return $query->execute( $valuesArray );
}
$updateArray = ['title' => $_POST["title"], 'label' => $_POST["label"], 'body' => $_POST["body"], 'updated' => 'NOW()'];
$db->update( 'pages', $_POST["id"], $updateArray );
```

What ia the best way to get arround this ? all my ideas are very hacky.

[image: Sql structure]

Comment: Put your SQL structure with datatype in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a `now()` function, i'm not sure which function is best but they both work.

```
function now() {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone( 'Europe/London' ) );
    return $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
}

function now() {
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London' );
    return date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
}
$updateArray = ['title' => $_POST["title"], 'label' => $_POST["label"], 'body' => $_POST["body"], 'updated' => now()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. The Database looks fine.

Change the query to this.

```
$query = $this->handle->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $values, updated=now() WHERE id = ?");
```

Update this

```
$updateArray = ['title' => $_POST["title"], 'label' => $_POST["label"], 'body' => $_POST["body"]];
```

I don't think there will be any harm to put the data like this. Comment below your result or any issue.

EDIT 1:

Change datatype of updated to DATE TIME in your database.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

$updateArray = ['title' => $_POST["title"], 'label' => $_POST["label"], 'body' => $_POST["body"], 'updated' => '$date'];
```

Comment: The problem with this is I want my class to be reusable on different database tables. I have tried if/else but that is very hacky. There must be a cleaner way.

Comment: If my answer resolves your issue mark as fixed. And to decide which code to select ask in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).